Spring Boot "kotlin-maven-plugin" not found
I created a new Spring Boot Project using the Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/). I didn't change anything after downloading. I entered spring-boot:run to run the application. I get the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.9.25:compile (compile) on project FlaPo2: Plugin not found: all-open -> [Help 1]

I added the following Dependencies

Spring Web
Spring Data JPA
Docker Compose Support
Spring DevTools
Spring Security

I tried to change versions of the plugin. I also have Internet Connection.
In the past already ran other projects created by spring initializr on the same machine and it worked.
If it helps: My Java Version is 21.0.4 and my Maven Version is 3.6.3. I use Kotlin.
This is my pom.xml File (I didn't changed anything after downloading it):

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.3.5
 

NeidenbergerEnterprise
FlaPo2
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
FlaPo2
Demo project for Spring Boot














<java.version>21</java.version>
<kotlin.version>1.9.25</kotlin.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-security


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


com.fasterxml.jackson.module
jackson-module-kotlin


org.jetbrains.kotlin
kotlin-reflect


org.jetbrains.kotlin
kotlin-stdlib

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <pluginOptions>
                    <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.persistence.Entity</option>
                    <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
                    <option>all-open:annotation=jakarta.persistence.Embeddable</option>
                </pluginOptions>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Try to add all-open plugin into compilerPlugins section:
    <compilerPlugins>
        <plugin>spring</plugin>
        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
    </compilerPlugins>


Yes, nice find. This was not initially added into pom when we initially create a spring-boot application from start.spring.io

Check with below 2 steps

Try add kotlin standard library

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


Additionally validate on below 2 steps if first step doesn't help

Check if properties section exists and contains kotlin version

<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.9.25</kotlin.version>
</properties>



Check if kotlin-maven-plugin (inside build->plugins->plugin) co-ordinate contains version and goals mentioned

        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

